# How i change text with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

https://prnt.sc/r9zh7k

I want change the 0,00 for another value, can anyone helps?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/205233)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
document.querySelector('[data-v-c35c6530]').innerHTML = "new text";
```

if you link the site, I can verify this will work.